# Multiple pipes in a single line wont compile

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr, forcats

I am having trouble understanding what goes wrong in the R-script below. Defining the varible levels before calling fct_expand results in a successful compilation, but when I insert the definition straight into fct_expand, R yields the error

> "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : attempt to apply non-function"

R-script replicating the error (Microsoft R open 3.4.0.0 and R 3.3.3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(magrittr)

f <- factor(1:3)%>% tbl_df
f_lev <- factor(1:6) %>% tbl_df

#This compiles just fine
levels <- f_lev %$% value %>% levels
f %>% mutate(value = fct_expand(value, levels)) %$% value %>% levels

#This wont compile
f %>% mutate(value = fct_expand(value, f_lev %$% value %>% levels)) %$% value %>% levels
```

EDIT: The code wont run on 3 of 4 machines tried running R 3.3.3 (The computer with no error have never had RTVS or Microsoft R open installed.). So it must be dependent on some settings I guess. The following example illustrates the same problem; on the machines which gives the error in the above the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(magrittr)

f <- factor(1:3) %>% tbl_df
f_lev <- factor(1:6) %>% tbl_df

f %>% {
   tmp <- f_lev %$% value %>% levels
   mutate(., value = fct_expand(value, tmp))
       } %>% str

f %>% {
mutate(., value = fct_expand(value, f_lev %$% value %>% levels))
      } %>% str
```

yields two different results:

```
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
$ value: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
$ value: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
```

While on the computer that does not give a compile error the latter code results in:

```
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
$ value: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3
Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
$ value: Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3
```

Comment: :The script is ok.It runs fine.Did you pasted correctly the code on the post?Or maybe it is a version issue.Try to update the packages.

Comment: It runs fine for me, too.

Comment: Please see my latest edit. One of four computers Running R 3.3.3 we didn't get the error. What could be the problem?

Comment: dplyr's version?

Comment: @F.Privé Version 0.5.0

Comment: @Martin **dplyr** has currently version 0.7.1. You should try to update it.

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. I was using Microsoft R open which would only allow me to update to 0.5.0, since this was the version availiable when i installed it.  Had to use the checkpoint package to solve it.